# How do I display the content of activity2 in a dialog Box that is called in activity 1?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, onactivityresult

I basically have an activity Which has several layouts for different contents. For example there is a switch statement that is responsible for switching between different content views. Each view contains a parameter which I determine through selecting a radio button. This choice is then retreived in my onActivityResult of my previous activity.

I want to do the same thing but rather going back and forth between these two activities I want the one with the parameter selections to display its content in a dialog box. So in other words when I click on something in Activity one a dialog box pops up with the content of one of the views of Activity 2.

How it was:

Activity 1------>Activity2
Activity2 data ---stored---> Activity 1

what I want now:

Activity 1 ---open dialog box----> dialog box contains Activity 2's parameter selection
I make my choices and when the dialog box closes the data is stored in Activity 1.

Is this possible?

If so how? If not what is another approach I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `LocalBroadcastManager`

Code in Activity 1 in oncreate() method:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(tempReceiver, new IntentFilter("dialogData"));
```

Outside of onCreate() method of Activity1

```
 private BroadcastReceiver tempReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
                 /* show dialog and 
                    you can get values same like bewlow code*/
            if(bundle!=null) {
                String dialogData;
                try {
                    dialogData= bundle.getString("your_key");
                  
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Code in Activity2 under `onBackpress()` method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("dialogData");
intent.putExtra("your_key", "yourVaue");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
finish();
```

In this code `yourValue` is value of selected views